# Getting a value inside URL using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to extract a value from inside a URL which follows this sort of pattern: my/url/{value}/test. I'm currently unable to extract the {value} only and nothing after {value}.

Here are some sample input:

`my/url/1Q23RTFKFK/test
my/url/RR43UHIR4U/test/qwerty`

With the following regex `(?<=url/)(.*)(?=/)`, I get the following result:

`1Q23RTFKFK
RR43UHIR4U/test`

I would like to get only the {value} from the URL:

`1Q23RTFKFK
RR43UHIR4U`

What am I doing wrong with my regex? Thanks.

Comment: `(?<=url/)(.*?)(?=/)`, or `(?<=url/)[^/]*`, or even `url/([^/]*)` will all work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you